# Solving first order ODEs system (not autonomous)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The task is to solve this system of ODEs:
$$
\begin{cases}
& x'(t)=x\sin t\\
& y'(t)=xe^{\cos t}
\end{cases}
$$

My problem is I have only been shown how to proceed when the system is autonomous. Here however both $x \sin t$ and $x e^{\cos t}$ have $t$ associated with them.

I've been looking for some examples on SE but most of them consist method using eigenvalues - I haven't been introduced to that yet so this case must be much simpler.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
& x'(t)=x\sin t\\
& y'(t)=xe^{\cos t}
\end{cases}$$

Solve first equation
$$(\ln x) '=\sin t \implies \ln x =-\cos t +c$$
$$x(t)=c_1e^{-\cos t}$$
Plug $x$ in the second DE. Then solve the DE:
$$ y'(t)=xe^{\cos t}$$
$$ y'(t)=c_1e^{-\cos t}e^{\cos t}=c_1$$
$$y(t)=c_1t+c_2$$

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is quite simple to integrate
$$ x'(t)=x(t)\,\sin (t) \implies x(t)=c_1 e^{-\cos (t)}$$
$$y'(t)=x(t)\,e^{\cos(t)} \implies y'(t)=???$$